# How to open a link from an UIwebview in an other webview xcode?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm new to iPhone development, I have an application in which I insert an `HTML` page (inserted locally in `UIWebView`) containing a summary, in this page there are links(href), when I click on a link its content is displayed in the same `UIWebView` but I want to keep the page containing the summary in the first `UIWebView` at left and display the contents of the link in a new `UIWebView` at right. I know from what I read that I should insert the method  `shouldStartWithLoad:` in the delegate.m but I do not know exactly how to use this method for my case.

Can you tell me how to do it? Is there a tutorial that explains this clearly?

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html

Comment: Please do not use code backticks to emphasize non-code wors such as "HTML".

Comment: Well it's my fist question here and i'm not good at english, thank you for editing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the uiwebviewDelegate method

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

if you pick the [request.URL absoluteString], then you can make your logic depending on the  the url. You need then to return NO.

By the way UIWebView take huge amount of ram, so you should take care.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for answering,as I said I'm new to iPhone development so my question can be stupid for you, but shall I do it like this? :

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
 if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    
  NSString *currentUrl = [[[webView request] URL] absoluteString];
  

 [webView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"currentUrl" ofType:@"htm"]isDirectory:NO]]];
  return NO;
 }
 return YES;}

Comment: Yes (even if it's a little hard to read). You should anyway check that the specified URL ([[webView request] URL]) match with the one you want to redirect, since all your link are kind of UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked

Comment: What does not work? Be specific: Is the callback method not called? inType who doesn't match UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked? Url who doesn't match what you want? Did your uiwebView is displayed?